# Como Contar Inteiros Repetidos a Cada 5 Valores Num Vetor OU a Cada Linha de Uma Tabela (Matriz Bidimensional, Exemplo: matriz[3][5] ) C++

Tags: array, c++, contador

Tenho um vetor que só tem os inteiros 1 e 2 alocados aleatoriamente. Exemplo:

```
int vetor[15] = {1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1};
```

Como o vetor seria impresso:

```
    1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1
```

Tenho esse mesmo vetor na forma de tabela (matriz bidimensional):

```
int tabela[3][5] = {{1,1,1,2,2},{1,1,2,2,2},{1,1,1,2,1}};
```

Como a tabela seria impressa:

```
    [,0][,1][,2][,3][,4]
[0,]   1   1   1   2   2
[1,]   1   1   2   2   2
[2,]   1   1   1   2   1
```

Note que há (no exemplo) 3 linhas  e 5 colunas, mas isso pode variar.

Seria possível **contar a quantidade do número 1** **a cada 5 valores** (no caso do vetor unidimensional) e **armazenar as respostas num vetor unidimensional**? Ou seja, cada índice do vetor é a resposta da contagem de uma linha.

Vetor de resposta:

```
    int resposta[];
```

**OU contar a quantidade do número 1 a cada linha** (que é o número de colunas no caso da tabela) **e armazenar as respostas num vetor unidimensional** (ou bidimensional, dispondo linha e resposta ao lado)?

```
int     respostaTabela[][2];
```

De qualquer maneira os valores armazenados no vetor resposta seriam:

```
resposta[0] = 3

resposta[1] = 2

resposta[2] = 4
```

A impressão do vetor ficaria:

```
3 2 4
```

A atribuição de valores à tabela resposta seria o mesmo que (primeira coluna para enumerar a linha e segunda coluna para mostrar a contagem):

```
int   respostaTabela[][2] = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

E a impressão ficaria:

```
[0,]   1   3
[1,]   2   2
[2,]   3   4
```

Obrigado pela atenção, um abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Achei eu mesmo a resposta das três possibilidades:

1ª (a partir do vetor):

```
  int contador5 = 0;

  int k = 5;

  int l = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i += 5)
     {
      for (int j = i; j < k; j++)
        {
           if(vetor [j] == 1)
              {
                contador5++;
              }
        }
     respostaVetor[l] = contador5;
     
     contador5 = 0;
     
     k+=5;
     
     l++;
     }
```

Impressão do primeiro código:

```
    3 2 4
```

2ª (a partir da tabela armazenando as respostas em um vetor):

```
int   numeroLinhas = 3;

int   numeroColunas = 5;

int   contador5_tabela = 0;

for (int linha = 0; linha < numeroLinhas; linha++)
 {
    for (int coluna = 0; coluna < numeroColunas; coluna++)
    {
       if(tabela[linha][coluna] == 1)
         {
          contador5_tabela++;
         }
   }
   respostaTabela[linha] = contador5_tabela;
   
   contador5_tabela = 0;
 }
```

Impressão do 2º código:

```
    3 2 4
```

3ª (a partir da tabela armazenando as respostas em outra tabela, fazendo uso da 1ª coluna como índice de referência à linha da tabela original):

```
   int   respostaTabela_indice[3][2];
   
   for (int linha = 0; linha < numeroLinhas; linha++)
   {
      for (int coluna = 0; coluna < numeroColunas; coluna++)
      {
         if(tabela[linha][coluna] == 1)
           {
            contador5_tabela++;
           }
      }
      
    respostaTabela_indice[linha][0] = linha;
      
    respostaTabela_indice[linha][1] = contador5_tabela;
      
    contador5_tabela = 0;
    }
```

Impressão do 3º código:

```
    [,0][,1]
[0,]   0   3
[1,]   1   2
[2,]   2   4
```

Agradeço a Deus e a todos os colegas que me ajudaram em outros lugares ou deram atenção à mensagem. Espero que sirva de ajuda a quem tiver dificuldades na mesma área Um abração!